# Cant see my Recyclerview Cardview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-cardview

I can't seem to get my adapter to attach. I'm trying to create a Recyclerview cardview. However, it will not display on the emulator. Ive get an error message:

> `E/RecyclerView`: No adapter attached; skipping layout.

Here is where I set the adapter.

```
madapter = new CardAdapter( itemList, CardviewRecycler.this );
recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter); 



          public class CardviewRecycler extends AppCompatActivity {
        // URL string to call data from myPHPAdmin localhost database.
        private static final String URL_ITEMLIST = "http://192.168.240.1/ImageJsonData.php";

        public RecyclerView recyclerView;
        //private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        private  CardAdapter madapter;
        public List<ItemList> itemList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardviewrecycler);

            // Initializing ItemList Array.
            itemList = new ArrayList<>();


            //Calling the Recyclerview
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


            //Loading the RecyclerView data.
            loadItemListData();
        }

        public void loadItemListData(){

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ITEMLIST,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                //converting the string to json array object
                                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                                //traversing through all the objects
                                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                    //getting item object from json array
                                    JSONObject itemobj = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int id = itemobj.getInt("id");
                                    String image_title = itemobj.getString("image_title");
                                    String image_url = itemobj.getString("image_url");

                                    ItemList item = new ItemList(id, image_title, image_url);
                                    itemList.add(item);
                                }

                                //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                                madapter = new CardAdapter( itemList, CardviewRecycler.this );
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(madapter);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });

            //adding our stringrequest to queue
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
        }

    }
```

Here is where my Adapter Class.

```
        public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    //Bringing in the ItemList java Class.
    private List<ItemList> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public CardAdapter(List <ItemList> itemList, Context context) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        //Inflating the cardview.xml from the LayoutInflator parent Context.
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // To bind the itemList data with the UI elements from the cardview.xml written in
        //the ViewHolder subclass. The UI elements are inside the holder object.
        ItemList itemlist = itemList.get(position);

        //The holder object is used to bind the cardview.xml UI element to the itemList data.
        holder.ImageTitleTextView.setText(itemlist.getImage());

        //The holder object is binding the cardview.xml  UI elementimageView to the itemList
        // data using the Glide dependecy in the build.gradle file.
        Glide.with(context)
             .load(itemlist.getImage())
             .into((ImageView) holder.itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        //itemList.size to show the items in the Array list.
        return itemList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //Creating UI elements from the cardview.xml
        TextView ImageTitleTextView;
        ImageView VollyImageView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //Initializing the UI elements above to Views(itemView)
            ImageTitleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImageNameTextView);
            VollyImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.VolleyImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Item List data that Im pulling in from myPhPadmin

```
        public class ItemList
{
    private int id;
    private String image_url;
    private String image_title;

    ItemList(int id, String image_url, String image_title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.image_url = image_url;
        this.image_title = image_title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image_url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return image_title;
    }
}
```

and this is my cardview layout file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
card_view:contentPadding="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ECEFF1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/VolleyImageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/VolleyImageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/VolleyImageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="@string/JSonImage"
        android:id="@+id/ImageNameTextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in the Itemlist you are getting but you also need to set for each get - eg - public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

Comment: try calling setAdapter before loading list, and adapter.notifydatasetchanged() after data loading.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting list item fields properly.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemList itemlist = itemList.get(position);
        holder.ImageTitleTextView.setText(itemlist.getTitle()); // you were setting getImage here 
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(itemlist.getImage())
                .into(holder.VollyImageView); // you were setting image on itemView which is not an ImageView.
    }
```

And you should use `wrap_content` for list item views. If you put `match_parent`, your one item will cover all screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" //changed this
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached

This is just a warning, you can ignore this.

Comment: I see my mess up there. Thanks! But I still having the same problem. Ive added the adapter.notifydatachange() in my method and moved the setAdapter to the onCreate. Ive added the setters in my ItemList class. Ive made made the corrections to the item list in the Adapter class...as well as wrap_content on the layout height.      Any other suggestions?